# Solving PDE using characteristic method

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the partial differential equation
$x\ u_ x - u\ u_y = y$ with the initial condition
$u(1,y) = y$ , using the mathod of characteristics.
My problem is with y and z , I mean

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = -z$$
$$\frac{dz}{dt} = y$$
How can I solve these two?
Is the solution unique? What is the maximal domain where it is defined?

Comment: Can you please format your question properly in Latex? I think you forgot the $'s

Comment: Is the PDE $xu_x-u u_y = y$ ?

Comment: @Cesareo  Yes. I have just edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a linear system for $x,y,z$ That splits into two subsystems. You can solve the system for $(y,z)$ using matrix exponential methods or just taking the t-derivative in one of the equations and combining with the other. Either way your solution is 
$$
y=C_1\cos t+C_2\sin t,\quad z=C_1\sin t-C_2\cos t
$$
You also have $x=C_0e^t$ so you can find the constants from your initial data on the initial curve.

The solution of a linear system is defined everywhere and unique through any given point.

Comment: @GReyesThanks GReyes. The question about the uniqueness and the maximal domain was about the PDE. What is your idea about it?

Comment: The projected characteristics clearly intersect so you do not have a unique smooth global solution. You do have a unique solution in the neighborhood of any point of your initial curve.

Comment: @GReyesWe have $$x(s,t)=e^t$$    $$y(s,t)=s(\ cost - \ sint)$$ $$z(s,t)=s( \ sint + \ cost)$$. How can we identify the characteristics and their projections to $xy-plane$.

Comment: The projections are just  $x(s,t)$ and $y(s,t)$. You can have $x(s_1,t_1)=x(s_2,t_2)$ only if $t_1=t_2=t$ and then $y(s,t)=0$ with, say, $t=\pi/4$ and any $s$. What that means is that the projection of the characteristics issued at $(1,s,s)$ intersect at $(e^{\pi/4},0)$. At that point the value of the solution $u$ must be $\sqrt{2}s$, thus different along each characteristic. Whenever that happens you have to issue a shock and resort to weak solutions. You can also see the collision of the characteristics from Cesareo's answer, choosing $C_1$ and $C_3$ appropriately.

Comment: Thank you. It was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

Regarding the PDE (it remembers a Hopf type PDE)

$$
x u_x-u u_y = y
$$

we have

$$
\dot x = x\\
\dot y = -u\\
\dot u = y
$$

from then we can extract

$$
y\dot y + u\dot u = 0\\
u\dot x+x\dot y = 0
$$

representing the characteristic families

$$
y^2+u^2 = C_1\\
$$

and after substitution

$$
\pm\frac{\dot y}{\sqrt{C_1-y^2}} =-\frac{\dot x}{x}
$$

or

$$
\pm\arctan\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{C_1-y^2}}\right) = -\ln x + C_2
$$

as characteristic curves.